Circular in the definition of set of natural numbers in PA axioms and in model theory
I'm learning set theory, which leads me to some confusion in model theory.
For the definition of the set of natural numbers, it is the set $\mathbb{N}$ which satisfies Peano axioms. (Ref: https://www.math.wustl.edu/~kumar/courses/310-2009/peano.pdf). I understand this.
In model theory, it is said that the set $\mathbb{N}$ together with the operations $(+, ×, <, 0, 1)$ is a model of Peano Axioms. I understand that a structure is a model of a theory if it satisfies every sentences (i.e. the axioms) of the theory. Until here I get lost. It is because the set $\mathbb{N}$ was defined to satisfy the Peano Axioms, then what is the point of saying that it is a model for the Peano Axioms ? (of course, it is a model because it is defined to be a model).
What do you think about it ? Thank you!

I alluded to this in comments under one of your previous questions already, but in ZFC one can prove there is a unique set $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying certain properties (namely, the second-order logic version of Peano arithmetic), which, again, in ZFC, can then be proved to satisfy the (first-order version) of Peano arithmetic. And that is one interpretation of what it meant to say $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies PA.

The reference you linked to seems to follow the above interpretation, since the principle of induction in the reference is written in its second-order form, which uniquely determines $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism (within the background of ZFC). A more Platonist version (which is what I usually meant when I say $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies PA) is that $\mathbb{N}$ is considered an object that actually “exists” in some sense, and it satisfies PA. Though it doesn’t make sense under this interpretation to define $\mathbb{N}$ as an object that satisfies PA.

@DavidGao: hey, good to see you again in this thread :p. Many thanks! As I understand from your comments, you talked about ZFC and that we can construct $\mathbb{N}$ in ZFC, then we can prove that this $\mathbb{N}$ actually satisfies the Peano Axioms. But i'm a little bit confused, in this case, Peano Axioms are no longer "axioms" (but theorems), right ? Because as for me, there is no proof for axioms and when there is a proof, they are theorems. (P/s: I'm reading the book of David Marker which is a good book for a self-learner like me, thanks for your suggestion).

In a sense, yes, it is a theorem in ZFC that the constructed $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the axioms of PA. This is really the usual way things happen. Lots of definitions of a kind of objects are given by a list of conditions which we usually call axioms for that kind of objects. For example, groups, rings, and fields are all defined by some lists of conditions and those conditions are routinely called axioms of groups, rings, and fields, respectively. They are “axioms” in the sense that if you want to prove some general properties of the said class of objects (groups, rings, or fields), then…

… those axioms are exactly the basis for any logical reasoning. That is to say, if you want to prove some properties of, say, groups, then you can start with the axioms for groups and those are exactly what you can use as the starting point of your logical deductions and a proof of them is not required to apply those axioms. But if you construct a specific object in ZFC and you want to apply the theory of groups to it, then you must prove (as a theorem of ZFC) that the said object satisfies those axioms, so we can then say the said object is a group…

… those groups are then exactly models of the axioms of groups, which then allows you to also use model theory techniques if you so wish. Now, there is a small difference between this and PA, but only a philosophical difference, which is that, while people accept that there are lots of different groups, we usually think there is just one object that is the set of natural numbers. So it’s weird to say that PA characterizes “a set of natural numbers” and that it can be considered a definition…

… and then in ZFC we can show that $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies this definition and is therefore “a set of natural numbers”. It’s strange because as opposed to groups, again, we don’t think there are multiple “sets of natural numbers”. Perhaps, to avoid confusion, we should do something similar to calling all objects that satisfies the first-order axioms of the set of real numbers a real-closed field, and just similarly call all objects satisfying first-order PA axioms as a “natural number semiring” or something, but that is hardly a standard notation…

… perhaps because, as opposed to the case of real closed fields, where there are natural and intuitive examples other than $\mathbb{R}$, there’s no such examples for PA, where the only “natural” model is $\mathbb{N}$ (to be clear, there are lots of different models, just that those models require advanced machinery to construct and are considered nonstandard). But regardless, thinking in those terms might reduce the confusion somewhat.

Also, a small note, there are such things as redundant axioms, which can be proved from other axioms, but which are included in a list of axioms regardless for historical, aesthetic, or clarity reasons. And in model theoretic terms, all axioms are automatically theorems, so this distinction is not that clear-cut. (But, again, this is not what happens in the specific case of proving $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies PA in ZFC. That was explained in my earlier comments. ZFC and PA are different theories, so this doesn’t really mean anything as to whether PA should be called axioms.)

@DavidGao: Thanks for your amazing answer!! I have a small question please. The structure "class of all sets" + $\in$ is a model of ZFC. Do you know if there is any proof for this ? I think, like the case of PA, this structure is defined by using a certain set of axioms (to describe the behaviors of things in this structure), and then we see if these behaviors are aligned with the axioms of ZFC. But as the axioms of ZFC are already very abstract/general. I couldn't think of something which can be used as starting point to define a structure in which axioms of ZFC are theorems.....

....I'm very appreciated if you can give me some insights about this question. Any hints, directions of thoughts, or references are more than welcomed because i'm quite lost and I couldn't find any reference talking about the proof of the model of ZFC. Many thanks!

There are no such proofs. As you said, the “class of all sets” is sort of defined to satisfy ZFC. Or, to put it another way, mathematics nowadays basically accept that there is such a thing as a structure that satisfies ZFC, which we interpret as the class of all sets, and in which most mathematics are performed. Now, there are even stronger systems in which you can construct models of ZFC and prove they satisfy the axioms of ZFC, similar to the fact that you can construct models of PA and prove they satisfy the axioms of PA in ZFC…

… Some systems of this nature include ZFC + “the existence of an inaccessible cardinal”, or MK. But that sort of just reduces the question to those even stronger systems and what are their models. And at a certain point there is some system that we just have to accept has a model. ZFC is just a relatively widely accepted choice for that.

@DavidGao: wow, it is crystal clear. Thanks very much for your help so far. Wish you every best things in life and see you in the near future with other questions!

Even if we take it for granted that the natural numbers exist and satisfy these axioms (without, say, passing the buck to a set theoretical construction), it would still be prudent to show that only the natural numbers (up to isomorphism) satisfy these axioms.
So say $(\mathbb N',\sigma',1')$ satisfies the axioms, and let's construct an isomorphism to the natural numbers structure $(\mathbb N, \sigma,1)$. Clearly we must send $1'\mapsto 1$, $\sigma'(1')\mapsto \sigma(1)=2,$ etc. What we worry about is that there might be something left over in $\mathbb N'$ after we have done this mapping... i.e. some element $z\in \mathbb N'$ that is "unreachable", in the sense that $z\notin\{1',\sigma'(1'),\sigma'(\sigma'(1')),\ldots\}.$ So let $S\subseteq \mathbb N'$ be the set of reachable elements. Well, $1'$ is obviously reachable, and if $x$ is reachable, then so is $\sigma'(x)$ (by one more application of $\sigma'$), and thus by the induction axiom, $S=\mathbb N'.$ Thus there are no unreachable elements and we can verify the corrspondence $\sigma^m(1)\leftrightarrow(\sigma')^m(1')$ is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb N, \sigma,1)$ and $(\mathbb N', \sigma', 1').$
Note this argument makes rather slick use of second-order induction where I can just conjure up any property I like ("reachability" in this case) and apply induction to it. It may even feel a little "circular" or "non-rigorous" in that notions like $\{1',\sigma'(1'),\sigma'(\sigma'(1')),\ldots\}$ and $\sigma^m(1)$ make implicit or explicit reference to the concept of the natural numbers. To worry about this latter issue is to miss the point of this particular exercise, which is not foundational in nature, but an ordinary mathematical verification that a set of axioms is doing what we intend it to do. (Which is not to say I couldn't have been much more careful and explicit in how I presented the argument.) As evidence that there is really something worth worrying about here, see this educational article, where a plausible alternative set of "Peano Axioms" is exposed as not characterizing the natural numbers up to isomorphism.
Also, note that unlike what you wrote later, the axioms in the linked note make no reference to arithmetic operations, only the successor operation. These axioms are a second-order theory often called the Peano axioms and are quite distinct from the similarly-named theory of first-order arithmetic known as PA. As mentioned, we made crucial use of second-order induction. The natural numbers with their usual operations do satisfy PA, but since PA is a first-order theory, the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem implies it can't characterize anything up to isomorphism. (And even worse, Godel's incompleteness theorem implies it can't even characterize the first-order properties of $(\mathbb N,+,\times,<,0,1)$.) So it's not useful for "defining" $\mathbb N.$


For the definition of the set of natural numbers, it is the set ℕ
which satisfies Peano axioms.

That's not how the set ℕ is normally defined. Such a definition would indeed not make sense, since we have to show that a set like this exists.
The paper you linked to doesn't really define the set ℕ.
ℕ is usually defined by using von Neumann ordinals. You painstakingly define ordinals, take the first infinite ordinal $\omega$ (using the axiom of infinity in the process), call that set ℕ, then you define $+$ and $\times$ on it.
And then, once you have built this elaborate construct, you can prove that it satisfies Peano axioms.

I’d say it’s perfectly reasonable to define $\mathbb{N}$ as the structure that satisfies the Peano axioms, insofar as it’s the second-order version. The usual construction and the proof that the second-order PA determines $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism can then be considered as proof that this definition is well-defined. This is also how I would approach the definition of real numbers, that is, defining it as the unique ordered field with the least upper bound property, instead of insisting on a specific construction since that is in some sense a distraction from what real numbers truly are.

@DavidGao Well at the very least the paper is missing the proof that this definition works, which is what prompted the OP to ask the question about circular claims (ℕ is defined as something that satisfies the properties, those properties have a model given by ℕ).
But also ambiguous definitions are a bit shady (although they can be considered OK). ℕ is not the unique set that satisfies this, it's just that they are all isomorphic.

Plenty of things are defined up to isomorphism, so I don’t see why that’s an issue. And it’s not like when we think of $\mathbb{N}$, or $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{R}$, we necessarily think of a specific construction for these objects. If you insists on that, for example, you can’t even say $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which would be ridiculous to anyone who’s not a set theory specialist.

With a bit of care it's easy to define a specific set ℝ so that it is a super-set of a specific set ℕ.
If we take your approach of "let's define ℕ to be any set satisfying second-order Peano axioms" and "let's define ℝ to be any complete ordered field", then you also don't automatically have the property that $ℕ\subset ℝ$. So getting that property requires more work either way.

That “bit of care” is also not how usually $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are defined. If you’re already accepting that you can change the definitions a bit to make sure the desired inclusion holds, and also accepting that somehow, even if the definition and therefore the specific sets defined change, the result can still be considered as $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, then you’re already adopting the viewpoint that these structures are characterized more by their properties, not the precise constructions you’re using…

… as otherwise you would only be able to say that there is something isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset, but not $\mathbb{R}$ itself, which is a statement that, again, is just ridiculous to say for anyone who’s not a set theorist and honestly even for set theorists. Whereas if you define these structures based on properties, then $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ can easily be interpreted as saying for any complete ordered field there is a natural subset that satisfies the second-order PA.

I admit that most people that provide unique definitions end up defining ℝ and ℕ to be disjoint, but those people are just doing it wrong because they usually end up contradicting themselves, later using $ℕ\subset ℝ$. Similarly, those people that define  "let's define ℕ to be any set satisfying second-order Peano axioms" and "let's define ℝ to be any complete ordered field" also are doing it wrong, because they later end up using $ℕ\subset ℝ$ which doesn't follow from their own definitions. It is actually sometimes useful to know that $ℕ = \omega$, so my specific definition has that benefit.

@DavidGao "ℕ⊂ℝ can easily be interpreted as saying for any complete ordered field there is a natural subset that satisfies the second-order PA". No, "⊂" is a symbol that has a specific meaning, it makes no sense to reinterpret it to mean something else.

The fact that $\mathbb{N} = \omega$, in the sense of that precise von Neumann ordinal $\omega$, is really only meaningful in very specialized set theoretic context. I’m not sure how that highly specialized use should outweigh the general intuition basically everyone follows.

Abuse of notation is a quite natural part of mathematics. It is routine to say, for example, that a unital algebra over a field $k$ contains $k$ as a subset, or that a metric space is a subset of its completion, or that a topological space is a subset of its compactification. Strictly speaking, none of these is true. We say these things anyway because everyone understands what it means and interprets the statement in the intended manner…

And the statement also provides notational simplicity and leads to better intuitive understanding. Insisting on notational purity just creates unnecessary and frankly ridiculous impediments to understanding.

@DavidGao So first you complained that under my definition "you can’t even say ℕ is a subset of ℝ, which would be ridiculous". Then I said that actually it is true under my definition but not under yours. Now you are saying it is a "ridiculous impediment to understanding" to insist that ℕ actually be a subset of ℝ and you just want it to be a figure of speech that is technically false xd

Hello, the discussion of 2 of you is very helpful. I personally think you are actually saying the same thing but from different philosophy. As for me, I agree with Tomek that ⊂ has its meaning and we can't rigorously interpret it differently and in anyway, I see that at some point we will have to define $R$ and $N$ as disjoint sets if we want only 1 $R$ and 1 $N$ while ignoring their isomorphic versions. In the meantime, the perspective of David is also perfectly fine for me because "why must I care about a specific $N$ while fundamentally they are all the same thing but with different names?"

@TomekCzajka I was not originally complaining about the specific statement $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$. I was simply disagreeing with your statements that the paper OP links to “doesn't really define the set $\mathbb{N}$”, “ambiguous definitions are a bit shady”, and the people defining $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ the usual way “are just doing it wrong”. And the reason I brought up $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ was to make a point that if you insist on not being “ambiguous” according to the standard you seem to be proposing…

@TomekCzajka … then you’re basically invalidating all basic intuition and understanding on the subject for notational purity that I don’t think anyone should really care about except in extremely specific set theoretic context. That’s all. I don’t mean to offend. And since we seem to have already laid out both of viewpoints and are unable to reach an agreement, I propose we just agree to disagree.

@InTheSearchForKnowledge Yeah. This is fundamentally a philosophical disagreement. I don’t think it matters much for any practical purposes.
